# Number of $x^3$ required to equal $2002^{2002}$.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

While working on math problems, I came upon a high-power summing problem, and got bogged down.
The problem is as follows:
What is the smallest positive integer $t$ such that there exist integers $x_{1},x_{2}, \dots, x_{t}$ with $x_{1}^3$ + $x_{2}^3$ +...+ $x_{t}^3=2002^{2002}$.
I think that it means to find the minimum value of t where t is the largest base among the sum of the cubes of these bases.
However, I am completely lost, and don't know how to solve this type of problem.
Can someone help? :)
Also, this problem is from the mods section of the book, so maybe use mod 2002 or something?

Comment: If the $x_i$ are restricted to positive integers, then at most $9$ are needed, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waring%27s_problem.

Comment: This is ISL 2002 N1.  We can get it in $4$ cubes.  The idea is that $2002=10^3+10^3+1^3+1^3$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$2002^{2002} =(2002^{667})^3. (10^3+10^3+1^3+1^3) $

$=(2002^{667}×10)^3+(2002^{667}×10)^3+(2002^{667}×1)^3+(2002^{667}×1)^3$

It seems $t=4$ is minimum as 2002 can be expressed as a minimum of 4 cubes.

Comment: See this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163283/expressing-20022002-as-a-sum-of-cubes/163291#comment3595771_163291